# Which perl can I use from the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, interpreter

Can anyone recommend me a Perl interpreter that can run on Windows command line to read LCOV files (and generate a report of some sort)?  I looked at genhtml, and it seems to need a lot of setup and must run in the bash shell environment, which doesn't sound good for Windows command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The easiest perl to use on Win32 is ActiveState's [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/).
- [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) gives a more "normal" Perl experience (it includes a C compiler and make so you can do normal CPAN style installs).
- Finally, [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a full on Unix environment for Windows.  Perl is one of many tools that are available for Cygwin.
- [Indigo Perl](http://www.indigostar.com/indigoperl.htm) is something of an also-ran, but they do have a nice kit for testing web apps.  They ship an Apache, mod_perl, perl combo that is very easy to get started with.
- [win32.perl.org](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a useful resource that you should check out.

Comment: I bullet-pointed your post because it makes more sense that way. +1 for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Perl interpreters that run on Windows include Cygwin and ActivePerl.

Do you already have a perl script for reading genhtml files?

Comment: There is Strawberry Perl as well.

Comment: I have Cygwin installed. But problem is everytime I run it, I need to get into linux mode first, then I can enter the genhtml xyzabc command, which is not very friendly if I want to automate a process using Windows command line.

Comment: Cywgin executables are the same as Windows executables. You can run Cygwin commands from the Windows command line (or in a `system` call from a Windows port of Perl) by specifying the full path to the executable (for example, `C:/cygwin/bin/genhtml.exe`) or including the Cygwin binary directories (like `C:\cygwin\bin`) in your `%PATH%` variable.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "get into linux mode".  Do you mean run a BASH (or other) shell?

As mobrule points out, Cygwin executables are simply windows programs.  Using a CMD prompt, CD into your %CYGWIN%\bin directory and do a "dir".  You will see that all the commands are there and have the .EXE extension.

I often call Cygwin commands from within .BAT (or .CMD) scripts.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion (I'm not a linux person). Yes I think I need to get into the bash shell first before entering the actual command of interest. I'm aware of the EXE files in the bin directory of Cygwin, but do not know how to use them to generate a report from LCOV files. There is a tool called genhtml which reads LCOV files and generates a html report from it. I tried to use that tool in windows command line, but got stuck on how to write the commands in .bat file and get into linux bash shell then to the actual command of interest.